# Grails integration test fails with "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter"

Tags: grails, integration-testing

Grails v3.3.9 and jsonView 1.2.10

I have a domain class query that fails when running an integration test  with class my Domain class Device, extends ManagedEntity (abstract) which extends RootEntity (also abstract).  Device has two static withCriteria queries to do eager fetches.

domain class Device.groovy:

```
Device extends ManagedEntity {
OrgRoleInstance org
Site site
Location location
NetworkDomain domain //can only be in one domain or zero
ProviderNetwork vfNetwork  //can be part of one CSP network domain
//simpler option than deviceRoles - not an entity in this case but  a join table
Collection<Resource.ResourceRoleType> roles = [] // creates device_roles table no versioning */
Collection<FlexAttribute> attributes = []
Collection<Equipment> buildConfiguration = []
Collection<Interface> interfaces = []
Collection<Alias> aliasNames = []


boolean freeStanding = false
boolean testDevice = false
Product product  //ref to portfolio offering if exists
String deviceStatus = "Operational"  //or Ceased or ...
String licenceType  //e.g. for cisco 903 would be one of  "metro servcices", or "metro Ip services", "metro aggregation services"
String licence = "none"
String memory
String storage
String numberOfCpu
Software runtimeOS

boolean isTestEntity () {
    testDevice
}

boolean isFreeStanding () {
    freeStanding
}

static hasMany = [deviceRoles: Resource, roles: Resource.ResourceRoleType, attributes:FlexAttribute, buildConfiguration: Equipment, interfaces:Interface, aliasNames:Alias]

static belongsTo = [org:OrgRoleInstance]  //dont at providerNetwork as belongs to as we dont want cascade delete



static constraints = {
    org nullable:true
    site nullable:true
    location nullable:true
    roles nullable:true
    domain nullable:true  , validator : {NetworkDomain domain, Device dev ->
        //assumes org has been set
        if (domain == null)
            return true
        if (dev.org == null)
            log.debug "org was null, trying to validate domain is in orgs.domains list - so org must be set first"
        NetworkDomain[] validDomains = dev?.org?.domains ?: []
        boolean test = validDomains.contains(domain)
        test
    }
    vfNetwork nullable:true , validator : {ProviderNetwork vfNetwork, Device dev ->
        if (vfNetwork == null)  return true
        OrgRoleInstance vf = OrgRoleInstance.findByNameAndRole ("Vodafone", OrgRoleInstance.OrgRoleType.ServiceProvider)
        ProviderNetwork[] networks = vf?.providerNetworks ?: []
        boolean test = networks.contains (vfNetwork)
        if (test == false)
            log.debug "Vodafone provider does not yet have any ProviderNetworks to validate to, please create and save any provider networks before assigning to device, then save "
        test
    }//ensure its in vf's list of provider networks }*/
    product nullable:true
    deviceStatus nullable:true
    licenceType nullable:true
    licence nullable:true
    memory nullable:true
    storage nullable:true
    numberOfCpu nullable:true
    runtimeOS nullable:true
    attributes nullable:true
    buildConfiguration nullable:true
    interfaces nullable:true
    aliasNames nullable:true
}

String toString () {
    "Device (manHostname:$manHostName, opState:$opStatus)[id:$id]"
}

//Queries
static Device getFullDeviceById (Serializable id) {
    Device.withCriteria (uniqueResult:true) {
        join 'domain'
        join 'providerNetwork'
        join 'site'
        join 'location'
        join 'runtimeOS'
        fetchMode 'product', FetchMode.SELECT
        fetchMode 'interfaces', FetchMode.SELECT
        fetchMode 'attributes', FetchMode.SELECT
        fetchMode 'aliasNames', FetchMode.SELECT
        fetchMode 'buildConfiguration', FetchMode.SELECT

        idEq (id as Long)
    }
}

//Queries
static List<Device> getFullDeviceBySite (Serializable sid) {
    Device.withCriteria (uniqueResult:true) {
        join 'domain'
        join 'providerNetwork'
        join 'site'
        join 'location'
        join 'runtimeOS'
        fetchMode 'product', FetchMode.SELECT
        fetchMode 'interfaces', FetchMode.SELECT
        fetchMode 'attributes', FetchMode.SELECT
        fetchMode 'aliasNames', FetchMode.SELECT
        fetchMode 'buildConfiguration', FetchMode.SELECT

        site {idEq (sid as Long)}
    }
}
}
```

My test integration test fails with this (as seen from test report)

```
<testcase time="0.0" name="build relationship between two CI " classname="com.softwood.domain.DeviceIntegSpecSpec">

<failure type="org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException" message="org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.softwood.controller.JsonApiRestfulController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

My pared-back test looks like this, which just calls the static query (data is loaded in Bootstrap):

DeviceIntegrationTestSpec

void "build relationship between two CI "() {

```
    given:

    Device pe = Device.getFullDeviceById(2)

    assert pe

    when : "build a ce and relate the CE and PE  "


    then:

        true


}
```

This appears to be objecting about my Controller class (which I'm not testing) which actually runs fine when i do a run-app (starts without errors).

How can I fix this? I am not sure if this is related:

[similar problem in someone's plugin](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11005)

If I fire up the Groovy console and run the query like this:

```
import com.softwood.domain.Device

Device pe = Device.getFullDeviceById(2)

println pe
```

this runs fine without errors - so it's something to do with launching the integration testing framework and not loading all my controllers. I want to write some integration tests and can't because this is a blocker.

Comment: ps.  project is on github here https://github.com/woodmawa/LCM-network-app

Comment: PPS, couple of days ago integration tests used to work - now i'm getting this.  but works fine when fire up for real

Comment: The `master` branch of the linked project will not currently build because of an unresolvable depends on `com.softwood:utils:1.0-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 0):

You have a controller `JsonApiRestfulController` that does not have a no-arg constructor.  Your constructor expects a `Class` parameter.  There is no way for Spring to know what `Class` to pass there so that is considered invalid.  You probably want that controller to be an abstract parent class.

**EDIT:**

The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/williamwoodmanconstructor simplifies your situation and eliminates most of the irrelevant stuff.  https://github.com/jeffbrown/williamwoodmanconstructor/blob/cb799545dfa76f78e8203e68cfadb09aed604544/grails-app/controllers/williamwoodmanconstructor/JsonApiRestfulController.groovy is the problem.

```
package williamwoodmanconstructor

import grails.rest.RestfulController

class JsonApiRestfulController<T> extends RestfulController<T> {

    JsonApiRestfulController(Class<T> c) {
        super(c, false)
    }
}
```

That is invalid.  You can verify that by running the app and sending a request to http://localhost:8080/jsonApiRestful/index.

Comment: If you make `JsonApiRestfulController` abstract, I expect this particular error will go away.

Comment: yes kind of and thankyou.  but still confused.  if i look at RestfulController<T> grails base i'm extending  as an intermediate to keep my controllers DRY, it is declared as class RestfulController<T> and also does not have a NO-ARGS constructor.  normally you have had your rest controller extend this and that seems to work.

Comment: what i have done is add my new DRY controller into sandwich so JsonApiRestfulController<T> extends RestfulContoller.  In similar pattern that new controller and just calls super in the constructor.   My real controllers now extend this new intermediate  and that started to break things.

Comment: I have made my JsonApiRestfulController abstract as you suggested - and that seems to have got my integration tests back working.  However i cant figure out when i call the grails RestulController (which is not abstract) works, but calling my JsonApiRestfulController failed.  they look to have the same structure at first glance.

Comment: my JsonApiRestfulController is sitting in the controllers folder (and therefore treated as a @controller bean.  Perhaps the RestfulController (despite having an @Artefact("Controller") annotation doesn't get treated as bean by itself because of where sits in the build tree?  However with making my DRY controller abstract the integration tests  are working again this morning, and thats the real benefit.  PS i've removed the softwoodUtils local dependency from build.gradle and repushed - so your local clone should now build suucessfully

Comment: Also i looked at your 'dumbed down' example and you only have the intermediate DRY controller.  what i was doing in my project was then extending from this, e.g. the DeviceController extends JsonApiRestfulController<Device> (which extends RestfulController).     it was this last step where i provided the class<?> def into the DRY controller.   Whilst this all worked when doing 'run-app', it didnt work in 'test-app -integration' so there is some difference somewhere between real and loading framework for integration tests that is different.

Comment: "Also i looked at your 'dumbed down' example and you only have the intermediate DRY controller. " - If you add other controllers, the `JsonApiRestfulController` will still be invalid unless you make it `abstract`.  I kept the project simple to demonstrate the problem.  Adding other classes doesn't address the problem and makes it more difficult to see what is going on.

Comment: "I have made my JsonApiRestfulController abstract as you suggested - and that seems to have got my integration tests back working." - Great. I am glad I can help.

Comment: "However i cant figure out when i call the grails RestfulController (which is not abstract) works" - Why `RestfulController` doesn't cause the problem you asked about is a separate question with a separate answer.